# Phpstorm TO GLOBAL path

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I downloaded Phpstorm (Linux version), and I can run the program by executing `phpstorm.sh` file in `/bin`.

But how can I run this from the terminal with the command `phpstorm`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathod 1:
Add the desired directory to the PATH

```
export PATH=/user/local/program_name/bin:$PATH
```

Change /user/local/program_name/bin with the location of your program.

then do:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Mathod 2:
Alternativly you can create a symlink by doing something like,

```
sudo ln -s /user/local/program_name/bin/phpStorm_executable_file_name.sh /usr/bin/the_name_under_witch_you_wish_to_start_the_program
```

Replace /user/local/program_name/bin/phpStorm_executable_file_name.sh with the correct path/filename